# Java - Can't delete file using File .delete()

Tags: java, file, csv, writer, reader

so I'm using the following code to basically delete one line from a file by writing a temporary file with everything but that one line and then deleting the old file and setting the new files name to the old one.

The only issue is that the `delete()` method and `renameTo()` method are both returning `false` no matter what I do.

I've looked at about 20 different questions on here and none of their solutions seems to be helping. Here is the method I'm using:

```
public void deleteAccount(String filePath, String removeID)
{

    String tempFile = "temp.csv";
    File oldFile = new File(filePath);
    File newFile = new File(tempFile);

    String firstname = "";
    String lastname = "";
    String id = "";
    String phonenum = "";
    String username = "";
    String password = "";
    String accounttype = "";

    try
    {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(newFile, true);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(bw);

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File(filePath));
        reader.useDelimiter("[,\n]");

        while (reader.hasNext())
        {
            firstname = reader.next();
            lastname = reader.next();
            id = reader.next();
            phonenum = reader.next();
            username = reader.next();
            password = reader.next();
            accounttype = reader.next();
            if (!id.equals(removeID))
            {
                pw.println(firstname + "," + lastname + "," + id + "," + phonenum + "," + username + "," + password
                        + "," + accounttype + ",");
            }
        }
        reader.close();
        pw.flush();
        pw.close();


        oldFile.delete();
        System.out.println(oldFile.delete());
        File dump = new File(filePath);
        newFile.renameTo(dump);
        System.out.println(newFile.renameTo(dump));
    } catch (Exception e)
    {

    }

}
```

The String that is getting parsed in to the `filePath` String is `"login.csv"` which gets read in an earlier method but the reader definitely gets closed.

EDIT: This is waht the login.csv looks like.

```
John,Doe,A1,0123456789,johnd,password1,Admin
Jane,Doe,A2,1234567890,janed,password2,CourseCoordinator
John,Smith,A3,2345678901,johns,password3,Approver
Jane,Smith,A4,356789012,johns,password4,CasualStaff
Josh,Males,A5,0434137872,joshm,password5,Admin
```

Comment: Can you add a few lines from login.csv?

Comment: I assume the problem would not occur if you'd use the [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) syntax, which makes sure that everything is closed again properly, and if you'd place your delete/rename code outside under the try-catch block.

Comment: Added everything in the login.csv file. also I'll give that a try Dreamspace

Comment: Try deleting an unrelated file and see if it works?

Comment: Tried deleting the file and it says it's being used by another program but the only thing it could be being used by is Eclipse itself

Comment: How about you try to print the exception stack trace. There might be something there.

Comment: When asking a question it is helpful to reduce the code to the smallest fragment that still exhibits the problem. This will also likely help you get a better insight in the problem yourself.

Comment: Your `csv` file may contain invisible characters. When I type the data using Notepad and saved as `csv` the program worked with no problem.

Comment: Have you tried this: 

`try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(newFile, true);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(bw);
 Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File(filePath));) {
// do the magic
}`

Comment: @Joshm102 Check file permission.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling the `delete()` method twice - once without using the return value (`oldFile.delete()`) and a second time with printing the return value (`System.out.println(oldFile.delete())`).

The second call will always return `false` - either because both delete attempts will fail for the same reason or because the first one will succeed (and therefore the second will fail since the file is no longer there).

The syntax you're looking for is something like this:

```
boolean deletionResult = oldFile.delete();
System.out.println("Deletion result is " + deletionResult);
```

Comment: Still getting false :/

Comment: Make sure the file is not opened anywhere else, for example in a text editor.